# Remove item of unknown type from list

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove an item from a List. However, I don't know the type of the objects in the List. Normally I would do it like that:

```
        var itemsSource = lsView.ItemsSource;
        var item = (Temperature)lsView.SelectedItem;
        var list = (IList<Temperature>)itemsSource;
        list.Remove(item);
```

Is it possible to do the same thing without knowing that the type of the item is "Temperature"? ...so I can use the same function for multiple lists with different objects

Comment: `dynamic item = lsView.SelectedItem;
        dynamic list = itemsSource;
        list.Remove(item);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the data source is some kind of `List<T>`, you can use the non-generic [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-5.0) interface, which is implemented by all generic lists.

`IList` has a [`Remove(object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.remove?view=net-5.0) method, so you can just pass it the selected item without worrying about its type.

```
using System.Collections;

IList itemsSource = lsView.ItemsSource as IList;
itemsSource.Remove(lsView.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the appropriate way. However, you should point out that you have to reference "using System.Collections;" Otherwise it might only recognize IList<> and will ask for a type. Which was probably my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the index property

something like

```
list.RemoveAt(lsView.SelectedIndex);
```

Alternatively if you want to use the same function for different object types, you can just include the type in your method call

```
public void RemoveSelectedItem<T>(ListView lsView){
    var itemsSource = lsView.ItemsSource;
    var item = (T)lsView.SelectedItem;
    var list = (IList<T>)itemsSource;
    list.Remove(item);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This probably works. However, with the second approach I would still have to mention the objects type at some point.